# Angular - Combining validations are not working

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I want to combine a set of validations to a bundle, and then re-use it, but it is not working for me, when I apply the validation bundle the control is always invalid.

`validation-bundles.ts` - Here I define my validation bundles:

```
import { ValidationErrors, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

export class ValidationBundles {

    static email(): Array<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return [Validators.required, Validators.email];
    }

    static password(): Array<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(50)];
    }

}
```

`login.component.ts` - Here I use the validation bundles for exmaple:

```
this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', ValidationBundles.email),
      password: new FormControl('', ValidationBundles.password)
    });
```

`login.component.html` - Here I define the validation error messages:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')">
    Password is required.
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['password'].hasError('minlength')">
    Mininum length is 6 characters.
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['password'].hasError('maxlength')">
    Maximum length is 50 characters.
</mat-error>
```

**So my questions:**

1. How do I make this work properly?
2. Can I add more validations to controls when I'm using a bundle? like merging the validations?
3. Are there any best practices related to this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right, just two minor improvements:

1. It's array of ValidationFns not ValidationErrors

```
export class ValidationBundles {

    static email(): Array<ValidatorFn | null> {
        return [Validators.required, Validators.email];
    }

}
```

2. You should call `ValidationBundles.email` like below and you will get what you need: array of ValidationFns

```
this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
   email: new FormControl('', ValidationBundles.email()),
   password: new FormControl('', ValidationBundles.password())
});
```

Comment: In addition: I needed to return the type: `Array<ValidatorFn>` and NOT `Array<ValidatorFn | null>`. And for the merging validations I have found that I can do: `ValidationBundles.password().concat([anotherValidatorHere()])`